# How to open mutliple instances of VS

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I'd like to know how to open multiple instances of Visual Studio, so that I can view code and files from seperate solutions at the same time.

Comment: The Visual Studio IDE allows you to open projects/solutions in the SAME window via the 'File..' Toolbar option.

Comment: just double-clicking on a solution in File Explorer should open a new instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem;

To open another instance of Visual Studio (I am using VS'19 on a Windows Computer
running Windows 10), you can **right-click** the VS icon on your taskbar and click
the words 'Visual Studio 2019'(this will open the Start Window), or click a recently opened project/solution/folder.

edit-
also, as user James pointed out, you can locate a .sln file on your computer (through file explorer) and simply double-click that.